# monitor though gpio

Tags: pi-gpio

I'm trying to put this (https://core-electronics.com.au/adafruit-1-14-240x135-color-tft-display-microsd-card-breakout-st7789.html?utm_source=google_shopping&gclid=Cj0KCQiAkuP9BRCkARIsAKGLE8XwQYVS1XQRsjU3OIjC6Ie67YsZyygecW5IgsnlXMugJFH5k80UOK4aAsGyEALw_wcB) monitor though gpio. so I can make an easy google glass. can i have some help to try and actach the lcd to gpio or hdmi

Comment: Good luck to you.   By the way do you have a question?  Please let us know what you have done so far.

Comment: Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

The screen will not connect to HDMI as it uses SPI to connect and the bandwidth through this will not give anything like real-time video so at best you will get text / polygon drawing.

First, you need to look at how you connect SPI to the Pi.

- Watch voltage as some SPI are 5v and some 3v3 - look at level converters if needed
- Wiring for SPI devices is well documented - I would start here [on the RPF website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md) SPI0 is common to all models of Pi (it helps if you say what Pi you are planning on using).

Then you need to enable SPI on the Pi

- The basic driver for SPI communications is built in (see above link)

You then need to find out how to drive the device itself.

- You could look to port the Adafruit library over from MicroPython
- You could look to use [this PyPI library](https://pypi.org/project/RPI-ST7789/) but you will not learn as much as the port :-)

Basically the steps are:

1. Create a display object
2. Create an image (BMP) of the correct size
3. Use the Python PIL / Pillow tools to 'draw' into the image created in step 2
4. Once done, the display object can have the image displayed on it with the `display` method

There are some brave folk out there who have got these displays mirroring screens (Google Mirroring HDMI to ST7789) but my eyes are not good enough.

Note: Other search engines that Google are available - I use this as the verb not noun.